# Postfix not connecting to postgres pool with local ip address

Tags: email, postfix, postgresql, stunnel

I have a `postfix` e-mail server that is contacting a database to query and verify e-mail addresses etc. It connects using `pgbouncer` to cycle through connections, however my problem was that the 'bouncer' is located on the database end so connections to and from the database are unencrypted and could potentially be a security issue.

I installed a local instance of `pgbouncer` on the mail server along with `stunnel` to at least give the two the chance to instigate an SSL connection between the two, however for some infurating reason, `postfix`, through sentimentality, perniciousness or just because it is plain stubborn refuses to comply with the switchover. Here is an example of one of the virtual alias lookup files located in the postfix directory:

```
# -------
# p-alias
# -------
hosts=10.0.0.123
port=6432
dbname=mail
user=user1
password=password
query=SELECT destination FROM v_alias WHERE source = '%s'
```

to test it, you can query a test e-mail address like so

```
console:~$ postmap -q test@testy.net pgsql:/etc/postfix/p-alias
```

and the result:

```
tester.mc_testy_tester@test_email_address.com
```

all fine and good, now to create a nearly identical config that points to the local pooler

```
console:~$ cp /etc/postfix/p-alias /etc/postfix/p-alias2
console:~$ vi /etc/postfix/p-alias2
```

change the ip to localhost:

```
# -------
# p-alias2
# -------
hosts=localhost
port=6432
dbname=mail
user=user1
password=password
query=SELECT destination FROM v_alias WHERE source = '%s'
```

pose it the same command:

```
console:~$ postmap -q test@testy.net pgsql:/etc/postfix/p-alias2
```

and it spits out the following error

```
postmap: warning: connect to pgsql server localhost: could not connect to server: Connection refused??
Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting??
TCP/IP connections on port 5432??
could not connect to server: Connection refused??
Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting??
TCP/IP connections on port 5432??
postmap: fatal: table pgsql:/etc/postfix/p-alias2: query error: Operation now in progress
```

The two bouncers are all but identical, the pgbouncer.ini files are the same, as is the userlist.txt, the only noticable difference being their physical location and connection. Because I do not have `psql` client installed on the e-mail server (trying to install through linux distros tried to add far too many dependencies for my liking), I instead resorted to mimicking the queries with python to check that I hadn't missed anything silly:

```py
import psycopg2

conn = psycopg2.connect( "host='10.0.0.123' port='6432' dbname=mail user='user1' password='password'" )
dbh = conn.cursor()
dbh.execute( "SELECT destination FROM v_alias WHERE source = 'test@testy.net'" )
dbh.fetchone()

# Result:
# ('tester.mc_testy_tester@test_email_address.com',)

conn.commit()
conn.close()

# -----------------------------------
# All is tickety boo, as it should be
# now let's repeat with the local ip
# -----------------------------------

conn = psycopg2.connect( "host='localhost' port='6432' dbname=mail user='user1' password='password'" )
dbh = conn.cursor()
dbh.execute( "SELECT destination FROM v_alias WHERE source = 'test@testy.net'" )
dbh.fetchone()

# Result:
# ('tester.mc_testy_tester@test_email_address.com',)

conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

both worked without a hitch, so as far as I can tell this is working and there should be no problems. Postfix clearly thinks otherwise.

So then I assumed that perhaps it was the stunnel that was the problem, here is the config:

```
client = yes
pid = /var/run/stunnel.pid
[pgbouncer]
        protocol = pgsql
        accept = 6433
        connect = 10.0.0.123:5432
```

I bypass the pgbouncer and query the local stunnel

```
# -------
# p-alias3
# -------
hosts=127.0.0.1
port=6433
dbname=mail
user=user1
password=password
query=SELECT destination FROM v_alias WHERE source = '%s'
```

postmap refuses to comply

```
console:~$ postmap -q test@testy.net pgsql:/etc/postfix/p-alias3
postmap: warning: connect to pgsql server 127.0.0.1: could not connect to server: Connection refused??
Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting??
TCP/IP connections on port 5432??
postmap: fatal: table pgsql:/etc/postfix/p-alias3: query error: Operation now in progress
```

no luck.

For the sake of completeness here is a fair chunk of the pgbouncer.ini

```
[databases]

; ...
;mail = host=localhost port=6433 dbname=mail
mail = host=10.0.0.123 port=5432 dbname=mail

[pgbouncer]

listen_addr = *
listen_port = 6432

; ...

auth_type = md5

auth_file = /etc/pgbouncer/userlist.txt


pool_mode = transaction

server_reset_query = DISCARD ALL

server_check_query = SELECT 1

server_check_delay = 30

; ...
```

I try pgbouncer with stunnel, or without and straight to the database and postfix refuses to accept there is a localhost, it works with python, and fails with postmap.

Clearly it just doesn't like localhost.

So, Postfix, what do you want from me?!!!

(Postfix is version 2.11.0)

Answer (score 0):

After some discussion on irc, it was pointed out that Postfix does not appear to be honoring the `port=` setting for local connections - the error message was clearly attempting to speak to port 5432, so changing the pgbouncer listen port to 5432 fixed the problem.

Thanks -Myon!

(it's always so simple once you know the answer...)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the manpage here:

http://www.postfix.org/pgsql_table.5.html

The optional port needs to be specified in the **hosts** fields with the `hostname:port` syntax:

> ```
>   hosts  The hosts that Postfix will try to connect to  and  query  from.
>           Specify unix: for UNIX-domain sockets, inet: for TCP connections
>           (default).  Example:
>               hosts = host1.some.domain host2.some.domain:port
>               hosts = unix:/file/name
> ```

An independant **port** field does not seem to exist.